# p-tabMenu throw "No provider for Router!" exception

Tags: typescript, angular, primeng

Good day. I want to create a simple tabmenu like in tutorial of primeng, I want just to display it. But I get "No provider for Router!" exception.
This us component with tabmenu:

```
<div class="ui-g">
    <h1>Heeey!</h1>
    <p-tabMenu ([ngModel])="menuItems"></p-tabMenu>
</div>


@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: './Views/test.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, DataScroller, DataGrid, Panel, TabMenu],
    styleUrls: ['../../Styles/EntranceStyle.css'],
    providers: [Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    public _tests: TestModel[] = new Array<TestModel>();
    public products: TestModel[] = new Array<TestModel>();

    private menuItems: MenuItem[];

    ngOnInit() {

        this.menuItems = [
           { label: 'Coffee'},
           { label: 'Sweets'},
           { label: 'Salads'},
        ];
    }
}
```

I declared **ROUTER_PROVIDERS** in boot: `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS, AUTH_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy} )] );`

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use? There were some changes in latest versions regarding routing...

Comment: @ThierryTemplier version is 2.0.0-rc.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should update (both projects are still in development and router has been changed and enhanced lately) to latest `primeng` and the corresponding supported `angular2` version to the date; this means: `primeng-beta9` and `angular2-rc3` (july/2016).

Then, you need to create a `RouterConfig`, in file `app.routes.ts`:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {path: '/', component: MyComponent}
]

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

And then add them to the `boot.ts`:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms(),
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

In the `AppComponent` you need to specify the router directives:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    templateUrl: 'my.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent {
//... blahblahblah
}
```

Remember to add the `<base href="/">` in the `<head>`.

source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Good answer! One thing, you can add the "<base href="/">" or you can add "provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue : '/' })" to the bootstrap. 
Also, be careful with updating the libraries, read the docs and check if it doesn't break your project.
I will leave here a demo http://plnkr.co/edit/zQ43rV?p=preview :)